# Complete trace of a program

Tags: kernel, logs, debugging

I am trying to figure out a way to write a debugger in the kernel space. I have some user space program and when I run it, I want to see its entire execution trace that happens in the kernel space. I would like to have the logs pertaining only to this program and not the entire kernel space's log.

I have tried using kprobes and ftrace, but they require the programmer to actually insert debugging points in the kernel either dynamically or statically. Since I am trying to come up with a generic debugger, I don't really know which functions in the kernel I should be monitoring to insert the debug points.

Are there any tools available to perform this task? I don't really recall a tool's name, but when that is used, it usually prints out the entire kernel's trace but not with respective to the program that I am running alone.

Comment: What do you mean by an `entire execution trace`? There is no reason not to enable ftrace on every function in the kernel apart from performance. You could potentially put a kprobe on the start of every basic block. In general the perf registers will probably not have enough capacity to do what I would call a full trace.